# Gmaps4rails: How to load markers according to map position?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Imagine the situation:

- City A has 3 markers;
- City B has 5 markers;
- City A and B are neighbors.

My app has a feature that allows the user to choose an initial city to load on map. So, if a user selects "City A" as initial, after logging in, the map will centralize and load only the 3 markers of "City A". Perfect!

However, when this user goes to "City B" via drag and dropping, no markers will be loaded in "City B". How can I load the markers of "City B", or another city, when user goes by dragging and dropping?

Thanks!

Comment: `bounds_changed` is triggered when you change the map position, so add a listener on it and trigger ajax queries to get the new markers if relevant. Check the reference for all events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: @apneadiving, great! Now I have another doubt hahaha! Having the latitude and longitude of `bounds_changed` method, is it possible to get new markers using only google maps? Any kind of method brings the markers that are near to?

Comment: I dont understand what you want. "using only google maps" ? how could it guess your markers?

Comment: Using Rails, I could retrieve the markers around a specific latitude and longitude using `geocoder` gem. It's just use `nearbys` method and passing the default latitude, longitude (got with `bounds_changed` for example) and the range in miles as parameters. I thought that google maps would have a native method like that if I load all markers at once on an array, for example..

Comment: not that I know, but why would you hide some markers if you have them all?

Comment: My app loads rent houses of a city. Each marker is a rent house. I'm trying to improve the user experience by retrieving automatically the markers of the neighbor city, when the users goes there by dragging and dropping. Nowadays, the user has to use the search engine, typing the neighbor city and submitting to get markers of another city and I can't load all markers of a state for example at once, it would be unnecessary mainly on big states.

Comment: ok so based on bounds_changed, load expected markers, keep or remove the one outside the current bounds